# How to bind HTML Drop Down List in MVC Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

in my project i'm getting IEnumerable collection, now want to bind this my Html Drop Down list
my razor view code is as:

```
 @if (Model.LanguageNavigationLinkItem != null)
     {
       // drop down list item Collection
       var ddlItem = Model.LanguageNavigationLinkItem;
       @Html.DropDownList(ddlItem.ToList(),"-- Select Item --")       
     }
```

i couldn't bind this collection with my drop down list please any one help me.

Comment: Post your controller code,

Comment: i'm not using controller i'm getting list collection using Glass mapper in sitecore

Comment: Let me know what are the values you get in your ddlItem list ?

Comment: I am asking about the ddlItem  containing properties

Comment: ddl item is IEnumerable<LanguageNavigationLinkItem> collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to bind dropdown using `ViewBag`. You can also use model to bind dropdown in similar way.

**Controller Code**

```
//Getting list of employees from DB.
var list = ent.Employees.SqlQuery(ent.Queries.FirstOrDefault().Query1).ToList<Employee>();
List<SelectListItem> selectlist = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (Employee emp in list)
{
   selectlist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = emp.Name, Value = emp.Id.ToString() });
}
ViewBag.SelectList = selectlist;
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("name",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SelectList)
```

Comment: i'm not using controller

Comment: i'm getting collection on view using glass mapper in sitecore mvc

Comment: Try this @Html.DropDownList("name",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ddlItem)

Comment: What is type of LanguageNavigationLinkItem ?

Comment: LanguageNavigationLinkItem  is interface