# unable to bind dropdownlist in mvc using viewmodel property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my viewmodel I've a getter property as below.

```
    [Display(Name = "Users System:")]
    public string UsersSystem { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SystemsList
    {
        get
        {
            List<SelectListItem> lst = new List<SelectListItem>();
            string[] UsersSystem = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UsersSystem"].ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });
            foreach (var item in UsersSystem)
            {
                lst.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item, Value = item });
            }

            return lst;
        }
    }
```

I need to bind the values to a dropdownlist but I m getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. My view has the following mark up

```
 @model GazetteerAddressRequest.Lib.Model.ChangeRequestModel

 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UsersSystem, Model.SystemsList , new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: You cant use the same name for the model property and the `SelectList`. What is the property you want to bind the selected UserSystem to?

Comment: Could you kindly explain why you can't have same name for the model property and the select list? yes I want to bind the model property `UsersSystem` to the select list

Comment: Have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797482/how-to-bind-html-drop-down-list-in-mvc-razor-view/27797734#27797734

Comment: `UsersSystem` is a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` A `<select>` control posts back a single value (a string which the `ModelBinder` can convert to a value type (`int`, `string` etc). How can a string be converted back to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property - and you don't even have a setter :) You need a property to bind the selected value to (say) `public string SelectedUser { get; set; }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have changed the property as per your comment (edited the question)  but still getting the same error.

Comment: @Learner, I was pointing out an error with your code, not addressing the `Object reference ...` error. Only you can debug and step through your code to find out where that's occuring

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. Clarified my concept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the model into view, otherwise the model will be null in view.

Eg. first you can pass the **SelectListItem** list into **ChangeRequestModel** and then that into the view.

```
public ActionResult YourPage(){
    return View(changeRequestModel);
}
```

Comment: Great thanks. As its a user input form, I did not pass in the model. But after passing the new model object it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As Stephen has mentioned you can't use the same name for the model property and the SelectList. Add a new property in `ChangeRequestModel` to hold the value of the selected item in the Dropdown.

```
public string UserSystemSelected { get; set; }
```

In your View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserSystemSelected, Model.UsersSystem, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Here you are populating the dropdown with `Model.UsersSystem` which has the list of all the `SelectListItem` and the VALUE SELECTED from the dropdown gets binded to `UserSystemSelected`.

EDIT:

You can also try this:

In your controller, inside the Action method

```
ViewBag.SystemList = new SelectList(
                         ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UsersSystem"].ToString()
                         .Split(',')
                         .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x, x)),"Key", "Value");
```

And in your View

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserSystemSelected, (SelectList)ViewBag.SystemList)
```

Comment: I have tried creating a new property as you and @Stephen suggested and then tried binding the getter property to the dropdownlist but it apparently does not make a difference